# Hive table delete information captured in Hive metastore

Tags: hive

When we delete a table from a Hive database, will information about this delete is captured in hive metastore tables?

Currently i am working on cataloging the hive metadata to Apache Atlas. i need to update Atlas whenever there is a table deleted in the Hive DB.
But in hive metastore tables not able to find information about table deletion in Hive DB. Hive actually deletes complete metadata of deleted hive table, does it not mark or capture this table deletion?

-

-

Comment: In case you are working on a cloudera distribution,  this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/q/53844461/1345973